# Why are [featured] questions not on the featured questions tab?

Tags: support, meta, bountied-tab, featured-tag

I think the title says it all. Why are [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) questions not on the [featured questions page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured)

Ps. I know they are two separate things but it makes for very poor UX to use the same term for two concepts.

Comment: This is MSE-specific, as this is the sole site where you can both tag questions as [tag:featured] *and* "feature" them with bounties. On most sites, you can only do one thing or the other: bounties can only be issued on main sites, while questions can only be tagged as [tag:featured] on meta sites.

Comment: We've mostly renamed the featured tab to bounties, so... it won't last much longer.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousWizHog so a question for meta.meta ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a quirk specific to this meta site, Meta Stack Exchange, since it's the only place where you can have both questions tagged "featured" and you can *feature* a question by placing a bounty on it.

The dual terminology is confusing nonetheless, so we've renamed the `featured` tab to `bounties`, so the issue is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).
As announced in [The "Featured" tab is now "Bountied"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332054/the-featured-tab-is-now-bountied)