# The "Featured" tab is now "Bountied"

Tags: discussion, bounties, homepage, announcements, questions-page

It's long confused me why we put bounties on a tab labeled "Featured" that has no connection to the "Featured" questions in the right sidebar. I [posted a discussion about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322629/is-featured-the-right-text-for-the-bounties-tab) earlier this year here on Meta Stack Exchange and the (small) response seemed to agree that this terminology mixture was confusing and that it'd be better to clean it up.

As we've been testing and then releasing the [Custom Filters](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/25/introducing-custom-filters/) this year, we actually already made this change without (to my knowledge) anyone being bothered by it. So, today we changed the "Featured" tab to read "Bountied" so that it's consistent for everyone, whether they have Custom Filters active or not.

[image: Screenshot of the top part of the page, showing the "Top Questions" banner, and the various sorting options, "Bugs", "Reqs", "Active", "Bountied", "Hot", "Week", and "Month".]

Thanks to the people who gave feedback on my question back in January and to Brian for making this change for us.

Comment: Excellent news :)

Comment: What do you mean with „people not having CFs activated“? AFAIK there is no preference to activate it.

Comment: Can we Feature this to add to the confusion of what is featured ;)