# Help center pages for bounties still refer to "Featured" tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, help-center

The "Featured" tab on the homepage [recently had its name changed to "Bountied"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332054/the-featured-tab-is-now-bountied).

However, the [help center page for bounties](/help/bounty) still refers to it as the "Featured" tab:

> The bountied question will appear with a special indicator in all question lists, and it will also be visible on the homepage Featured tab for 7 days.

Also, as Arulkumar commented, the ["set bounties" privilege page](/help/privileges/set-bounties) also refers to it by its old name:

> The question gets placed in the home page's **featured** tab for seven days.

Can these both please be changed to "Bountied" to match the new name of the tab?

Comment: Also in the [Set Bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) help page too.

Comment: @Arulkumar Also fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terminology has now been changed, thanks to @Catija. The [help centre page for bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) now reads:

[image]

Also, the ["set-bounties" privilege page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) now reads:

[image]