# The [featured-tab] tag should be renamed now that the "Featured" tab is now "Bountied"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta, retag-request

As we all know, [The "Featured" tab is now "Bountied"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332054/the-featured-tab-is-now-bountied).

However, on this site, we still have the [featured-tab](/questions/tagged/featured-tab) tag that refers to the old name of this tab.

This tag should be renamed to [bountied-tab](/questions/tagged/bountied-tab).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been completed; the [featured-tab](/questions/tagged/featured-tab) tag has been synonymized to [bountied-tag](/questions/tagged/bountied-tag).

As currently shown in the [tag synonyms page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms):

[image: screenshot of synonyms page]