# Rename "featured" tab to "bountied" tab in help center

Tags: feature-request, help-center, bountied-tab

Since for about an year [featured tab is renamed to bountied tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332054/468333) but the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) still mentions "Featured" tab:

> The bountied question will appear with a special indicator in all question lists, and it will also be visible on the [homepage Featured tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured) for 7 days.